# Why does gmail always add or delete some decimal part to the width of an item in email?

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I'm working on an email HTML template and I sent a test to my gmail account. I specified every `<td>` element's width and made sure all the `<td>` width in a row add up to exact the table width. But it seems to me that gmail always adds or deletes some decimal number for the `td` width I specified, which results in a little mismatch between the table width and the overall `td` width. And this mismatch will show a small gap between the border of the table and the last `td` in a row, which is kind of annoying to me.  Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Actually this mismatch only happens in gmail. Hotmail and yahoo don't have this problem.

The code is as follows:(there are some Chinese characters in it and you can just ignore them)

```
<table width="650" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 10px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 18px; font-size: 30px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'Microsoft Yahei', sans-serif;">
            <img border="0" src="http://m.bomoda.com/static/img/email/spacer.gif" style="display:block;" />    
        </td>
        <td width="297" style="vertical-align: top;">
         <table width='297' cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" height="175" style="width: 297px; height: 175px; line-height: 175px; max-height: 175px;">
                    <img border="0" src="http://m.bomoda.com/static/img/email/spacer.gif" style="display:block;" />       
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'Microsoft Yahei', sans-serif; font-size: 24px; color: #000001; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; line-height: normal;">
                    让<span style="color: #00bac9; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'Microsoft Yahei', sans-serif; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;">Bomoda</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'Microsoft Yahei', sans-serif; font-size: 24px; color: #000001; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; line-height: normal;">
                                        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" height="31" style="width: 297px; height: 31px; line-height: 31px; max-height: 31px;">
                    <img border="0" src="http://m.bomoda.com/static/img/email/spacer.gif" style="display:block;" />       
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'Microsoft Yahei', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000001; text-align: left; line-height: normal;">
                    <a href="http://www.bomoda.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><span style="color: #00bac9; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'Microsoft Yahei', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; ">Bomoda</span></a>Newsletter
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" height="36" style="width: 297px; height: 36px; line-height: 36px; max-height: 36px;">
                    <img border="0" src="http://m.bomoda.com/static/img/email/spacer.gif" style="display:block;" />       
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="116">
                    <a href="http://www.bomoda.com" target="_blank" style="display: block; text-decoration: none;">
                        <img border="0" src="http://m.bomoda.com/static/img/email/retention_email/button.jpg" alt="" style="display: block; width: 116px; height: 27px;" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td width="181">
                    <img border="0" src="http://m.bomoda.com/static/img/email/spacer.gif" style="display:block;" />    
                </td>
            </tr>       
         </table>    
        </td>
        <td width="315">
            <img border="0" alt="Bomoda" style="display: block; width: 315px; height: 458px;" src="http://m.bomoda.com/static/img/email/retention_email/A.jpg" />    
        </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, the 650-width table only have one row with three `td` in it. Their widths are 18, 297 and 315 respectively, which is equal to 630 in total(taking into account the table has 10-width border on the left and right). But when I use developer tools in chrome to see the width of each `td`, it shows me the calculated width of each `td` is 17.27272605895996, 296.3636169433594 and 315.45452880859375 respectively, which could not add up to 630. So there will be a small gap between the table border and the rightmost picture.

Comment: Don't use tables for layouts

Comment: But for email, I think I have to use table for layout if I don't want to use sliced images.

Comment: @Kansha tables are necessary for a proper layout in an html email.  I know it seems backwards but until email clients improve it is the best option for a consistant rendering.

Comment: can you show your current html?

Comment: @Jrod The code is there now.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an empty row with 2 cols above all the colspan'd rows. Sometimes you can have issues when you don't specify the col widths in the first row of the table.

Not sure if this will fix your issue, but I've had issues in the past with not setting the col widths first...